# Multiple converters for one connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

is it possible in Kafka Connector to have multiple converters for a single sink connector? For example we have a use-case whereby we receive data from a topic in format `A`, but wish to stream it into two locations, one in format `A`, and the other in format `B`. Is it possible to do this in a single connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sink connectors, the Connect framework uses the [converters](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html) to deserialize the messages *read* from the Kafka topics. The connector is then free to deliver those messages in whatever format it wants to the backend sink systems.

However, let's imagine that you have a single topic, T, that has messages serialized in format A, and you want to deliver this to multiple external systems, X and Y. The idiomatic way to do this with Apache Kafka and Connect is to have *one connector instance* consuming T (using converter for A to deserialize the messages) and writing to system X, and a *second connector instance* consuming T (using converter for A to deserialize the messages) and writing to system Y. These connectors are independent of each other, so a problem in system X might cause that connector to block while the other connector is free to continue consuming and writing to Y. In both cases, the *connector* is responsible for how it writes to the external systems. The *converters* are only used, in the case of sink connectors, to *deserialize* the messages read from the Kafka topics.

Why don't you want a single connector reading from a single topic T and writing to multiple external systems? Because the [dual write problem](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/27/logs-for-data-infrastructure.html) means that you might write to X but fail to write to Y. Or more specifically, you might read a message from T, write to X and Y, but find out that the request to Y failed. You can be sophisticated about retrying, but lots of things can go wrong, and it's just simpler to have two independent connectors.

Now, if systems X and Y are other topics in the same Kafka cluster, you probably just want to use Apache Kafka's [Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/). Streams applications are set up to continually read from Kafka topics, process the messages in a streaming manner to compute new messages, and write those new messages to *other* topics. But again, you probably want to have two independent streams topologies each consuming topic T and writing to topic X or Y.

Comment: I understand completely now - as you've identified, I was confused about the role of kafka converters. Thank you very much for an excellent answer :)